# PHP how to add data to spaces

Tags: php

I need to take data from a variable called `$destination` and add spaces between the info

So example:

```
echo $destination;
```

Would return: `123 Main St`
But I need it to return `123%20Main%20St`

So I need a script that will take the data from `$destination` and add `%20` in the spaces.

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998286/how-to-replace-a-string-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `urlencode()` to produce a string with percent encoding of special characters.

```
echo urlencode($destination);
```